# Como deixar conteúdo abaixo do menu fixo topo Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Olá, minha dúvida é o seguinte, estou tentando colocar um container-fluid exatamente embaixo de uma div fixed-top do Boostrap, aonde contem um Menu navbar e uma ul, tive que colocar para deixar os dois fixo no topo. Tive de usar css no Body para dar espaço no conteúdo, porque a div estava sobrepondo. Preciso saber se tem como fazer.

CSS:

```
body {
  padding-top: 200px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
 body {
     padding-top: 107px;
 }
}

<div class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Share Sound</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>                   

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <div class="container-fluid">           
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">      


                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                                        <label for="nav_pesquisa" class="fa fa-search"></label>
                                    </span>

                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisa" aria-describedby="Pesquisa" name="nav_pesquisa" id="nav_pesquisa">

                                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </div>
                             </form>
                        </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">      
                    <div class="btn-group dropdown" id="dropdown-form-topo">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="drop-login-cadastro" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Login / Cadastrar-se <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>

                          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-form-info" aria-labelledby="drop-login-cadastro">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="Email">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="Email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="Senha">Senha</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Senha" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                                            Check me out
                                         </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Fazer Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form> 

                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <small class="form-text text-muted">———— OU ————</small>
                                </div>

                                <div class="text-center" id="cad_conta">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cadastre-se</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>

    <ul class="nav nav-expand-lg nav-pills nav-fill" id="ul-menu-topo">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Perfil</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Discussões</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i>Músicas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>Recordes</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>


<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="cont-2">
        <div class="text-center" id="sub-titulo">       
            <center>
                <div id="back-title">
                    <p class="h2">Share Sound</p>
                    <span>Tentando proporcionar a arte tradicional da musica, <br>novas produções e 
                    infinitas possibilidades.<br></span>    
                </div>
                <img src="music4.jpg" class="col-md-12">    
            </center>               
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você usa jQuery?

Comment: @Dvdsamm Sim, uso

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta usando jQuery e veja se fica bom pra vc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução usando jQuery:

Apague do CSS esses códigos:

```
body {
  padding-top: 200px;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
 body {
     padding-top: 107px;
 }
}
```

Adicione o jQuery abaixo:

```
$(".navbar-toggler-icon").add(window).on('resize load click',function(e){
    espaco = 30; // ajuste de espaçamento à partir barra, em pixels
    if(e.type != "click"){
        $("body").css("padding-top",($("div.fixed-top").height()+espaco)+"px");
    }else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("body").animate({ 'padding-top': ($("div.fixed-top").height()+espaco)+'px' }, 50);
        },500);
    }
});
```

```js
$(".navbar-toggler-icon").add(window).on('resize load click',function(e){
 espaco = 30; // ajuste de espaçamento à partir barra, em pixels
 if(e.type != "click"){
  $("body").css("padding-top",($("div.fixed-top").height()+espaco)+"px");
 }else{
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("body").animate({ 'padding-top': ($("div.fixed-top").height()+espaco)+'px' }, 50);
  },500);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fixed-top">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container">

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Share Sound</a>

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>                   

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                    <div class="container-fluid">           
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-9">      


                            <form class="form-inline">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
                                        <label for="nav_pesquisa" class="fa fa-search"></label>
                                    </span>

                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Pesquisa" aria-describedby="Pesquisa" name="nav_pesquisa" id="nav_pesquisa">

                                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                                </div>
                             </form>
                        </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">      
                    <div class="btn-group dropdown" id="dropdown-form-topo">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="drop-login-cadastro" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Login / Cadastrar-se <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>

                          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-form-info" aria-labelledby="drop-login-cadastro">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="Email">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" aria-describedby="Email" placeholder="Enter email">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="Senha">Senha</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Senha" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                                            Check me out
                                         </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Fazer Login</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form> 

                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <small class="form-text text-muted">———— OU ————</small>
                                </div>

                                <div class="text-center" id="cad_conta">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cadastre-se</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>

    <ul class="nav nav-expand-lg nav-pills nav-fill" id="ul-menu-topo">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>Perfil</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Discussões</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-music" aria-hidden="true"></i>Músicas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i>Recordes</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>


<div class="container-fluid text-center" id="cont-2">
        <div class="text-center" id="sub-titulo">       
            <center>
                <div id="back-title">
                    <p class="h2">Share Sound</p>
                    <span>Tentando proporcionar a arte tradicional da musica, <br>novas produções e 
                    infinitas possibilidades.<br></span>    
                </div>
                <img src="music4.jpg" class="col-md-12">    
            </center>               
        </div>
</div>
```

O código ajusta o `padding-top` do `body` de acordo com a altura `height` da barra fixa no topo.

Comment: deu certo cara, vlw !

Comment: @GabrielMarangoni Legal! Marca a resposta como certa para ajudar outras pessoas tb.